# How to permanently set the position of a window in Looking Glass?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

This command currently allows you to temporarily set the position of a window in in Looking Glass:

```
global.get_window_actors()[1].set_position(0, 15)
```

However, when you then move the window afterwards, it jumps back to it's previous position.

Is there a way to permanently set the position of a window in Looking Glass? So, when you use it afterwards it doesn't immediately jump back to it's old position?